# Unexpected key "componentDataDependencies" found in preloadedState argument passed to createStore

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I get this errror when I build my Gatsby project.. It does still build, but the error appears in the terminal when i 'Gatsby build' and 'Gatsby develop'.. Anybody has any idea how I can fix this? Let me know if you need more from me!

```
Unexpected key "componentDataDependencies" found in preloadedState argument passed to createStore. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "nodes", "logs", "pages", "redirects", "schema", "definitions", "staticQueryComponents", "status",
"webpack", "pageData", "themes", "webpackCompilationHash", "config", "lastAction", "jobsV2", "pageDataStats", "components", "babelrc", "jobs", "nodesByType", "program", "resolvedNodesCache", "nodesTouched", "flattenedPlugins", "pendingPageDataWrites",
"schemaCustomization", "inferenceMetadata", "staticQueriesByTemplate", "queries", "visitedPages". Unexpected keys will be ignored.
```

Comment: Can you provide some code about your implementation? Otherwise it's impossible to know where this code comes from unless you've seen it yesterday

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same error and simple `'gatsby clean'` fixed it.